# Adding <jdoc:include type="component" /> displaying " Home" at the front end

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla3.0

I am building my first joomla site I am stuck here-
when I am including at my templates index.php.

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

It is displaying Home at my front end.
Can't find the solution need help.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the problem seen to be. Can you please explain in more detail with a possible screenshot?

Comment: I have modified my beez-20 joomla template to fit a HTML site,but it was not displaying article content so i included <jdoc:include type="component" /> now the article content are displayed but the position at which <jdoc:include type="component" /> is included it is displaying "Home"in the front end.

Comment: I can't include image because it require 10 reputation can you help me?

Comment: add the image to Photobucket and provide a link on here

Comment: http://s1315.photobucket.com/user/bhaveshj21/media/7c2d67ef-216f-4e96-9cce-8281c0102cc7_zps014ae54a.jpg.html?state=copy.      this is the link please reply soon

Comment: I think that might be the article title. You can simply turn it off it by opening the article in the backend, and disabling it in the options on the right hand side

Comment: Ok thank you It is done now.